# All dropdown options are missing in magento 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am working on magento 1.7. I cant find why all options in missing whole configuration area other side like catalog grid, compliation process is showing correct only problem is here anyone have fix for this issue

[image]

Comment: What are you missing exactly?

Comment: did you check screenshot. all options are missing from "select" dropdown or multiselect in only configuration sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These dropdowns are loaded from folder:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source
```

There should be, amonst others, a country.php file.